# XCode 12.5.1 (or swift?) is allowing guard to shadow a previous variable

Tags: swift, xcode, shadowing

On my setup (XCode 12.5.1), I am able to shadow a previously declared variable using a guard statement. On a colleagues setup (XCode 12.4), this fails for a reason that eludes me.

Why does the following pass on XCode 12.5.1, and not on XCode 12.4? Which change between the two version is allowing for this?

```
import UIKit

var strings: [String] = ["hello", "good day", "greetings"]

func greetings(greetings: [String]) {
    let hello = greetings.first

    guard let hello = greetings.first else {
        assertionFailure("faillure...")
        return
    }

    print(hello)
}

greetings(greetings: strings)
```

Comment: It looks as if https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-214 has been fixed now. But I cannot find this mentioned in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md.